# Rails Project Chartkick with Highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am adding charts on my Rails application and I started using chartkick the variety of charts that it offers are not quite what I would like.
I found in their documentation that you can use the Highcharts library. The issue is, I followed the steps but nothing happens...
Does anyone know the correct way to use these two together?

Here is the code I write: `<%= column_chart @prsd_data, xtitle: "Members", ytitle: " # of publications",  width: "100%", height: "100%" %>`

> @prsd_data is a hash that contains as keys the names of some people and as values an array of 2 integers.s

NOTE: The chart I want to generate is something like this one : [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic)

Comment: Can you provide us some code? Like when you try to call those charts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Add this `gem "chartkick"` to your gemfile

Add this `<%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.google.com/jsapi" %>` to your application.html.erb.
and you are good to go for any chartkick graph.